# documentContent возвращает чистую html-страницу

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Только пробую себя в программировании, поэтому могу звучать не совсем корректно. Хочу встроить svg-файл через object

`<object type="image/svg+xml" data="element.svg" id='object'></object>`.

Сам svg прекрасно отображается, однако по задумке он должен взаимодействовать с js. Попробовал следующим путем:

`var object = document.getElementById("object"); var svgDocument = object.contentDocument;  var svgElement = svgDocument.getElementById("svg4156");`

Однако мне выдало в svgElement значение null.
id у самого svg-файла прописан верно.

`<svg id="svg4156" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="589" viewBox="0 0 589 589" width="589" version="1.1" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">`.

С помощью console.log отследил, что происходит при инициализации svgElement - svg-файл из объекта, "завернутый" в #document, просто куда-то исчезает, а сам #document почему-то возвращает чистую html-cтраницу
Буду крайне благодарен за помощь!
(Снизу прикрепляю сам  html и svg).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Test SVG</title>
</head>
<body>
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="element.svg" id='object'></object>

 <script>
var object = document.getElementById("object"); 
var svgDocument = object.contentDocument;
console.log(svgDocument);
var svgElement = svgDocument.getElementById("svg4156"); 
svgElement.setAttribute("fill", "blue"); 
 </script>
</body>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="100"
   height="100"
   viewBox="0 0 100 100"
   id="svg4156"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.91 r13725"
   sodipodi:docname="xo.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs4231" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="1.4"
     inkscape:cx="212.97594"
     inkscape:cy="38.477127"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     units="px"
     inkscape:window-width="1366"
     inkscape:window-height="705"
     inkscape:window-x="0"
     inkscape:window-y="30"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata4234">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(0,-952.36216)">
    <g
       id="g4840">
      <path
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         id="path4185"
         d="m 25.484375,953.87779 -0.707031,0.70703 -3.535156,3.53515 -19.726563,19.72461 24.515625,24.51762 -24.515625,24.5156 23.96875,23.9687 L 50,1026.3309 74.515625,1050.8465 98.484375,1026.8778 73.96875,1002.3622 98.484375,977.84458 74.515625,953.87779 50,978.39341 25.484375,953.87779 Z m 0,2.82812 L 50,981.22154 74.515625,956.70591 95.65625,977.84458 71.140625,1002.3622 95.65625,1026.8778 74.515625,1048.0184 50,1023.5028 25.484375,1048.0184 4.34375,1026.8778 28.859375,1002.3622 4.34375,977.84458 l 18.3125,-18.31054 2.828125,-2.82813 z"
         style="color:#000000;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:medium;line-height:normal;font-family:sans-serif;text-indent:0;text-align:start;text-decoration:none;text-decoration-line:none;text-decoration-style:solid;text-decoration-color:#000000;letter-spacing:normal;word-spacing:normal;text-transform:none;direction:ltr;block-progression:tb;writing-mode:lr-tb;baseline-shift:baseline;text-anchor:start;white-space:normal;clip-rule:nonzero;display:inline;overflow:visible;visibility:visible;opacity:0.55899999;isolation:auto;mix-blend-mode:normal;color-interpolation:sRGB;color-interpolation-filters:linearRGB;solid-color:#000000;solid-opacity:1;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1;color-rendering:auto;image-rendering:auto;shape-rendering:auto;text-rendering:auto;enable-background:accumulate" />
      <path
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         style="opacity:1;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:20;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 25.48438,962.36216 10,977.84456 34.51563,1002.3622 10,1026.8778 25.48438,1042.3622 50,1017.8465 74.51563,1042.3622 90,1026.8778 65.48438,1002.3622 90,977.84456 74.51563,962.36216 50,986.87776 25.48438,962.36216 Z"
         id="path4816" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы ссылаетесь на внешний SVG-файл и не дожидаетесь его загрузки. Подключаемся к событию **load** и решаем первую проблему:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title> Test SVG</title>
</head>

<body>
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="element.svg" id='object'></object>

    <script>
        const svgObj = document.getElementById("object");
        svgObj.onload = () => {
            const svgDoc = svgObj.contentDocument;
            const svgPath = svgDoc.getElementById("path4816");
            svgPath.setAttribute("fill", "blue");
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Вторая проблема в том, что цвет зафиксирован в стиле контура и его приоритет выше чем атрибут **fill**. Проще всего будет подчистить стиль вручную.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! но, к сожалению, мне консоль все равно выдает ошибку, и теперь уже svgDoc возвращает как null.

Comment: Какую ошибку? @Daria Maliar

Comment: Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined

Comment: Вероятно, вы просто открываете html-файл в браузере, но так тестировать сайт нельзя. Нужен [локальный сервер](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server) @Daria Maliar

Comment: Спасибо, понял!